# Velocity of liquid in tank

Tags: fluid-dynamics, integration

How do i find the average velocity of efflux. I tried integrating v=√(2gx) from x to 0 then dividing by x. I have to find out the time it would take water to get empty till the hole in the tank.
I was trying to use A1/V1=A2/V2 to find the velocity of water in tank (V1) by finding average velocity of efflux (V2) by integrating √2gx.
Is it correct to solve this way?

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/50583) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/50583) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.